# Can we automate the BIOS screen using any tools?

Tags: automation, bios, sikuli

We have sikuli and other image recognition tools to automate, but is there any core tools which can identify the objects of BIOS precisely independent of resolution and others? Or any best way to do automation on BIOS screens.